# Error installing Bioconductor packages on AWS-EC2

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bioconductor

I'd like to install some Bioconductor packages on a new AWS account. But I keep getting errors (see output below).

Installing R packages (e.g., readr, ggplot2, haven) using install.packages() works fine.

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle" Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type 'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to quit R.

> source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") Bioconductor version 3.6 (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), ?biocLite for help
> biocLite("GEOquery") BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org Using Bioconductor 3.6 (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), R 3.4.1 (2017-06-30). Installing package(s) ‘GEOquery’ also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’, ‘httr’, ‘xml2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_3.1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 366086 bytes (357 KB)
================================================== downloaded 357 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_1.0.1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1194261 bytes (1.1 MB)
================================================== downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.3.1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 147593 bytes (144 KB)
================================================== downloaded 144 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xml2_1.2.0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 251614 bytes (245 KB)
================================================== downloaded 245 KB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/src/contrib/GEOquery_2.46.15.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13717934 bytes (13.1 MB)
================================================== downloaded 13.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'libcurl' found Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'libcurl' found Using PKG_CFLAGS= Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR --------------------------- Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:  * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)  * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris) If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/ec2-user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Using PKG_CFLAGS=
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR --------------------------- Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:  * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)  * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)  * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX) If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/ec2-user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl’
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Found pkg-config cflags and libs! Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include/libxml2
-I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include Using PKG_LIBS=-L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib -lxml2
-L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib -lz -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib -llzma -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lm -ldl
** libs g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c connection.cpp -o connection.o g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c xml2_doc.cpp -o xml2_doc.o packet_write_wait: Connection to XX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XX: Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to explain the issue - it can't find libcurl or openssl. Try installing those packages on that instance (not sure what OS you are running).

```
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. 
Try installing:  
    * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  
    * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)  
    * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris) 

If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. 
If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'


Configuration failed because openssl was not found. 
Try installing:  
    * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  
    * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)  
    * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)  
    * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX) 
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. 
If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
```

Comment: What if they're already installed and it's still giving that error?

Comment: Check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH (try `which pkg-config`) and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file (try `ls $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`)